# Вытащить данные из массива

Tags: php

Есть вот такой массив:

```
object(stdClass)#14466 (1) {
   ["COUNT(place_amount)"]=>
   string(1) "2"
}
```

Как из него вытащить значение "2"?
Сам запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT COUNT(place_amount) FROM wp_12ae_evpl_orders WHERE order_room = '$order_room'
```

Comment: `echo $obj->{"COUNT(place_amount)"};`

Comment: Не работает так.

Comment: Я создал аналогичный вашему объект и у меня всё работает. Приведите код, приведите код ошибки. Кстати ниже ответ(по сути  комментарий), который тоже решает вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал так

```
SELECT COUNT(place_amount) AS cnt FROM wp_12ae_evpl_orders WHERE order_room = '$order_room'

$res->cnt
```

Comment: Да, можно было и "COUNT(*) as count", проблема в том что мне нужно суммировать значения в place_amount при WHERE order_room = '$order_room', а в данном запросе просто суммируются количество строк в таблице.

Comment: SELECT SUM(place_amount) AS cnt FROM wp_12ae_evpl_orders WHERE order_room = '$order_room'